# React Navigation MaterialTopTabNavigator - indicator did not follow custom tab bar width

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I tried to customise the width of the tab bar. I managed to successfully do so, but the indicator is still consuming the whole width of the screen. Any idea on how to change the indicator width to follow the tab width? I know I can fully customise the tab bar, but is there any other way?

This is the current behaviour.
[image]

This is my configurations

```
const PersonalInfoTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    PersonalData: {
      screen: PersonalData,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'A'
      }
    },
    AccountSet: {
      screen: AccountSet,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'B'
      }
    },
    ModifyPassword: {
      screen: ModifyPassword,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'C'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'black',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        width: 300
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for React Navigation for React-Native](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html), it looks like you also have to set the style for the tabs in the `tabStyle` field:

```
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'black',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      width: 300
    },
    tabStyle: {
      width: 100
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to @ValdaXD to point out the 100 width.

Comment: I think it should be width:100

Answer (score 0):

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
    tabBarItemStyle: { width: 100 },
    tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' },
  }}
>
  {/* ... */}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

**tabBarItemStyle did the trick for me**